# results are getting adding up - may be memory issue

Tags: php

I have iterative execution of similar action. In each next iteration it seems result are getting adding up.

I have used `unset($word_count)` but even no change.

Is there anything wrong in below code?

If I check result for each of them individually then it gives correct result but for below case it gives added result for `$word_count`

```
        $select_words = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from review_details where rate = 5 and category = 'italian' and isApi = 0");

        while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($select_words))

        {

            //echo $row1[review]."<br>";

//          echo $row1[rate]."<br>";

            $word.=$row1[adjective].",";        

        }

        //echo "Words are : $word";

        echo "<br/><br/><strong> 5 star word count </strong>";

        $word_count = array_count_values(str_word_count($word,1));

        arsort($word_count);

        echo "<br>";

        echo "<br>";

        //var_dump($word_count);

        print_r($word_count);

        unset($word_count);
        unset($select_words);
        $select_words = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from review_details where rate = 4 and category = 'italian' and isApi = 0");

        while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($select_words))

        {

            //echo $row1[review]."<br>";

//          echo $row1[rate]."<br>";

            $word.=$row1[adjective].",";        

        }

        //echo "Words are : $word";

        echo "<br/><br/><strong> 4 star word count </strong>";

        $word_count = array_count_values(str_word_count($word,1));

        arsort($word_count);

        echo "<br>";

        echo "<br>";

        //var_dump($word_count);

        print_r($word_count);

        unset($word_count);
        unset($select_words);
        $select_words = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from review_details where rate = 3 and category = 'italian' and isApi = 0");

        while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($select_words))

        {

            //echo $row1[review]."<br>";

//          echo $row1[rate]."<br>";

            $word.=$row1[adjective].",";        

        }

        //echo "Words are : $word";

        echo "<br/><br/><strong> 3 star word count </strong>";

        $word_count = array_count_values(str_word_count($word,1));

        arsort($word_count);

        echo "<br>";

        echo "<br>";

        //var_dump($word_count);

        print_r($word_count);


        unset($word_count);
        unset($select_words);
        $select_words = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from review_details where rate = 2 and category = 'italian' and isApi = 0");

        while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($select_words))

        {

            //echo $row1[review]."<br>";

//          echo $row1[rate]."<br>";

            $word.=$row1[adjective].",";        

        }

        //echo "Words are : $word";

        echo "<br/><br/><strong> 2 star word count </strong>";

        $word_count = array_count_values(str_word_count($word,1));

        arsort($word_count);

        echo "<br>";

        echo "<br>";

        //var_dump($word_count);

        print_r($word_count);

        unset($word_count);
        unset($select_words);
        $select_words = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from review_details where rate = 1 and category = 'italian' and isApi = 0");

        while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($select_words))

        {

            //echo $row1[review]."<br>";

//          echo $row1[rate]."<br>";

            $word.=$row1[adjective].",";        

        }

        //echo "Words are : $word";

        echo "<br/><br/><strong> 1 star word count </strong>";

        $word_count = array_count_values(str_word_count($word,1));

        arsort($word_count);

        echo "<br>";

        echo "<br>";

        //var_dump($word_count);

        print_r($word_count);
```

It gives result for $word_count

1754
3815
4832
5174
5324

but actually it is

1754
2061
1017
342
150

Comment: And I assume the issue goes away if you remove any of those `echo "<br>";` lines? ;)

Comment: unset($word);  that's the key....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't unsetting, or resetting `$word`. You keep appending to the `$word` string by using `.=`. Therefore the count is always correct, you are counting the `$word` string which you continuously append words to.

If you don't want to continuously sum the amount of words after each call, then use `=` instead of `.=`.

For example, use this

```
$word = $row1[adjective].",";
```

Instead of this

```
$word.=$row1[adjective].",";
```

Or, if you want to keep appending to the `$word` string, create another variable to temporarily store the words for *only* that database call, that you can then perform a count on.

Comment: @Christuan: in that case it displays result for last fetched values only. Not all

Comment: @user123 Read my answer again. Do you understand what is happening? Each database call you make, you append words to the `$word` string. Then after each database call, you count the words string, which contains **all** the words from the other database calls, because you're appending to it. Like I said in my answer, if you want to keep appending to the `$words` string, then create another variable that you reset after each database call which you can count.